# Abstract class with only abstract methods

Tags: java, oop

Given an abstract class with only abstract methods, what would be the differences between this and an interface?

The only difference I can see would be related to the ability to use multiple inheritance with the interfaces.

Are there other important differences in this situation which would dictate whether to do this or use an interface instead?

Comment: I would call it **bad design**.

Comment: Java 8 or Java less than 8?

Comment: You can have static methods

Comment: @shmosel In Java 8 interfaces can also have static methods.

Comment: Interesting, good to know.

Comment: @ismail Can you define constructors in Java 8 Interfaces?

Comment: @blafasel no, you can't. But a better design would be having an interface with the methods and an abstract class implementing this interface that declares the desired constructors. In this way, the implementations of the interface may opt to directly implement the interface or to extends from the abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Abstract classes are meant to be inherited from, and when one class inherits from another it means that there is a strong relationship between the 2 classes. For instance, if we have an abstract base class called "Canine", any deriving class should be an animal that belongs to the Canine family (like a Dog or a Wolf). The reason we use the word "should" is because it is up to the Java developer to ensure that relationship is maintained.

With an interface on the other hand, the relationship between the interface itself and the class implementing the interface is not necessarily strong. For example, if we have a class called "House", that class could also implement an interface called "AirConditioning". Having air conditioning not really an essential part of a House (although some may argue that point), and the relationship is not as strong as, say, the relationship between a “TownHouse” class and the "House" class or the relationship between an “Apartment” class that derives from a “House” class.

Because a TownHouse is a type of House, that relationship is very strong, and would be more appropriately defined through inheritance instead of interfaces.

So, we can summarize this first point by saying that an abstract class would be more appropriate when there is a strong relationship between the abstract class and the classes that will derive from it. Again, this is because an abstract class is very closely linked to inheritance, which implies a strong relationship. But, with interfaces there need not be a strong relationship between the interface and the classes that implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

the ability to declare non public methods as abstract... the ability to set the abstract class to derive from other parent and by that provide the parent's methods to the sons.. the ability to determine what your Ctor will get and by that force the deriving class to "know" certain data

Comment: *Given an abstract class with only abstract methods, what would be the differences between this and an interface?* In fact, there's a bad design to have such abstract class: 1) If you inherit from another class, there's no real benefit since this abstract class adds nothing useful, 2) if you determine constructors for children classes, I would say it's more a restriction than a benefit when being compared with an interface, 3) since Java 8, you can have defaults methods in interfaces, which allows you to define behavior for methods in interfaces.